# Firebase Query Under AutoID Under Child Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My Firebase Database]

Hello! I'm trying to make two Firebase queries:

1. All children under `basicInfo`, for multiple users at once (query limited by 20 results). For example, in this query with the above database I will get all `basicInfo` sections for `-Kwz1eoUMPym...` and also for `-Kwzhj4pzBJxbb...`
2. All children under basic info where `name == (some name)`.

I can't understand how to approach a `name` query under the AutoID key and also under `basicInfo` key, for both queries.

What is the most logical approach to this?

Comment: I think you need to structure you info data under one tab. If you want a more NoSQL approach, you can just use firestore instead of realtime DB. Splitting the information wont make much sense unless you have major queries to perform. Once, done with that you easily perform a ‘queryorderbyKey()’

Comment: I actually need to make searches in the db, in order to find some users with LIKE clauses and no just =... So I think I will split some data between the Firebase Firestore and Firebase Database. Thanks!

Comment: Using both wouldn’t be advisable, since you’ll have to take care of alot of data handling in and out between the datastore. All that matters is your data model/architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database, and it's only possible to filter by direct descendents of children in a list. Therefore, you will need to use a flatter data structure, and avoid splitting your fields into `basicInfo`, `fullInfo`:

```
users
|- userId
   |- name: "John"
   |- age: 17
   |- gender: "m"
   |- birthday: "10.10.2000"
   ...
```

With this approach, you can attach a listener to the `users` node and then filter by child values using the `queryOrderedByChild` and `queryEqualToValue` methods. For example, something like this in Swift:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrderedByChild("name").queryEqualToValue("(some name)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, with: { snap in  
    // Do your thing with snap
})
```

With either of your structures, you can limit your results with the `queryLimitedToFirst` and `queryLimitedToLast` methods. For example, from the [filtering data section of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data):

> The following example demonstrates how example blogging app retrieves a list of the 100 most recent posts by all users:
>
> ```
> // Last 100 posts, these are automatically the 100 most recent
> // due to sorting by push() keys
> let recentPostsQuery = (ref?.child("posts").queryLimited(toFirst: 100))!
> ```

For more details on filtering and limiting Firebase data in Swift/iOS, see the [working with lists of data on iOS documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data).